# Woocommerce shows original file instead of cropped version

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Lately I have encountered some issues with woocommerce. For some products it does not show the cropped (resized) version of the catalog image anymore.
I set the correct size in the customizer and even tried to regenerate the thumbnails.

If I test it with the following code:

```
<?php
require_once("wp-load.php");

$new = wp_get_attachment_image_src(22296, 'shop_catalog');

echo "<pre>";print_r($new);

?>
```

It returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://xxxxx.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/model-peter-a_001.jpg
    [1] => 266
    [2] => 355
    [3] => 1
)
```

Whereas it should return

```
[0] => https://xxxxx.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/model-peter-a_001-266x355.jpg
```

The file "model-peter-a_001-266x355.jpg" exists on the server, but it does not load.
Instead it shows the original file.
This happens just lately. I updated Wordpress & WooCommerce to the latest version. Maybe this has caused it, but I have no idea why.

Comment: If the image is smaller than the specified wc image size, it won't upscale.

Comment: actually they are much bigger - as the "original" file gets loaded